# Unable to use global variables in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible: 2.4.2

So i looked all over the Internet but couldn't find a straight forward solution. I have 10 routers in a LAB to be configured with variables.

Now my variables are of 2 types: 
1. Lab specific
2. Router specific

The router specific variables should be specified in one vars/var.yml file while i need another variable file vars/var1.yml where I can specify the variables for the entire lab in order to avoid repetition.

But when i do this, my var1.yml file overrides the var.yml and obviously i get AnsibleUndefined errors. I tried doing it with defaults/main.yml but I read somewhere that "vars" overrides "defaults" so that is anyway not working.  Is there a way that I can achieve my goal ?

Comment: I can elaborate my requirement if someone replies rather than flagging the question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[host_vars/group_vars](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data) are useful to specify variables by hosts/groups